# How to scrape / use API in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to scrape content of the page using laravel?

How can you link an API in laravel app?

Here I have examples of content I need to scrape/API

Travel
https://beta.tfgm.com/public-transport/tram/stops/oldham-central-tram

Entertainment
https://github.com/ahmetabdi/odeon_api/wiki/Odeon-API-V3-Documentation   Oldham and Rochdale

News
http://www.oldham-chronicle.co.uk/news-features/

Social
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public @smoke_yard read the posts and images.

If it is not possible using Laravel, how can you do it using any other technology like PvP or maybe JS?

Can you also explain to me what content to do I get back and how can I use it? is it a JSON or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is irrelevant, any PHP application will connect to a 3rd party API, using either cURL, or an HTTP client like Guzzle.

Here's an article on using Guzzle to hook up to an API https://hackernoon.com/creating-rest-api-in-php-using-guzzle-d6a890499b02

Good luck!